# Enabling jqmPhp to function like Gmail mobi?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, gmail

I'm quite sure this has never been asked before.
I am new to jQuery and found [jqmPhp](http://www.jqmphp.com/%20jqmPhp) very easy to use. However, I am trying to achieve a few things that I find very complicated to implement.

I need to filter list items (like [here](http://demo.jqmphp.com/#simple-xml.php)) and enable the user to check/uncheck several list items to delete. I am trying to implement a similar feature to what Gmail mobile is doing (with a checkbox on the left, where selecting it will make the relevant row highlight and allows users to just click a button to delete checked rows).

Is it possible at all to do that with jqmphp? If so, can anyone assist me with more  information, links or code?

Comment: You want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vcXmK/

Comment: Whoah.. awesome.. not exactly like google mail mobi, but this is exactly what I need. THank you omar.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I made a **Demo** for you, by converting list-view into check-able list items.

http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vcXmK/

> HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
 <div data-role="header">
   <h1>Header</h1>
 </div>
<div data-role="content">
 <ul id="list-view-test" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
   <li><a href="#">Adam Kinkaid</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Alex Wickerham</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Avery Johnson</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Bob Cabot</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Caleb Booth</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Christopher Adams</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Culver James</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" id="del">Delete</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" id="reset">Reset</a>
 </div>
 <div data-role="footer">
     <h1>Footer</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

> Code

```
// Change icons
$('#list-view-test').find('span.ui-icon').each(function () {
 if ($(this).hasClass('ui-icon-arrow-r')) {
    $(this).removeClass('ui-icon-arrow-r').addClass('ui-icon-checkbox-off');
}
 $('#list-view-test').listview('refresh');
});

// toggle "checked/unchecked"
$('#list-view-test').on('click', 'li', function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $(this).find('span.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-checkbox-off').addClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on');
});

// Delete selected 
$('#del').on('click', function () {
 $('span.ui-icon').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on')) {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
        $('#list-view-test').listview('refresh');
    }
 });
});

// Clear selection
$('#reset').on('click', function () {
 $('span.ui-icon').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on')) {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on').addClass('ui-icon-checkbox-off');
    }
 });
});
```