# Combine a jquery mobile Checkbox in a listview along with a data-icon

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to insert a checkbox(not the normal checkbox) that has all jquery mobile css features in a listview along with a data-icon. Is it possible to do something like below?

[image]

I have been trying like below.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" />
<a href="#page4"><h3>Task 1</h3><p>Lorem ipsum order no have may not be</p></a></li>
<li>
<a href="audi.html"><h3>Task 2</h3><p>Lorem ipsum order no have may not be</p></a></li>
<li>
<a href="bmw.html"><h3>Task 3</h3><p>Lorem ipsum order no have may not be</p></a></li>
<li>
<a href="acura.html"><h3>Task 4</h3><p>Lorem ipsum order no</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

But i get something like this,With no css styles for checkbox. Plz help on this.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your custom class and any other custom CSS you have

Comment: Well i have not added any custom css or class,Here custom class refers to the default jquery-mobile class and all css related code comes in jquery-mobile.css. All i wanted is a jquery mobile checkbox i.e the default one. Hope you got it!?

Comment: you mean like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15989777/1771795

Comment: @omar: Partally Yes.In your Jsfiddle you are having a checkbox. But What i need is a checkbox that can toggle along with a data-icon="arrow-r" image which represent a list. Both checkbox and data-icon="arrow-r" images should be next to each other just like the way how it is in above image. I have been trying to get that pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of this: Check this fiddle with check box in list view included with data-icon.

http://jsfiddle.net/ek2QT/184/

markup:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="d">
            <li>
                <div class="checkBoxLeft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="detailListText">Message 1 </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkBoxLeft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="hidden-checkbox" checked="checked" />
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="detailListText">Message 2 </a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Code:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        ($(this).is(':checked')) ? $(this).parent().parent().addClass('checked') : $(this).parent().parent().addClass('not-checked');
    });
});

$('.checkBoxLeft').bind('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
       $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('not-checked'); 
       $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked' , false);
    } else {
       $(this).removeClass('not-checked').addClass('checked');             
       $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked' , true);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.detailListText{
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.checkBoxLeft{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 10px; 
    top: 28%;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 3px;  
}

.hidden-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.not-checked, .checked {
    background-image: url("http://www.dragan-gaic.info/elements.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.not-checked {
    background-position: 18px 0;   
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
}


.checked {
    background-position: 0 0;   
    background-color:#6496bc;    
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thats what i wanted,that should solve my problem. Thank you sheetal.

Comment: This is largely hacked together outside the jQM framework. Is there anyway to use the jQM framework to accomplish something like this or is it a bit rigid when it comes to things like this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the icon position example at http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/checkbox/

The checkboxes need to be wrapped in a label, which you can then style

You can see in this http://jsfiddle.net/peter/ckWDG/

That the checkbox with a label renders correctly while the one without a label looks like a regular html checkbox.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="" />
<a href="#page4"><h3>Task 1</h3><p>Lorem ipsum order no have may not be</p></a></li>
<li>
<a href="audi.html"><h3>Task 2</h3><p>Lorem ipsum order no have may not be</p></a></li>
<li>
<a href="bmw.html"><h3>Task 3</h3><p>Lorem ipsum order no have may not be</p></a></li>
<li>
<a href="acura.html"><h3>Task 4</h3><p>Lorem ipsum order no</p></a>             <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0 ">
    </label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes. I got that point. But i wont be able to see the other image i.e data-icon="arrow-r". I added it separately to my list and then inserted in label. But i failed to generate both data-icon="arrow-r" image and jquerymobile checkbox in the same list. Sorry, I am just a newbie.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle save it and update your question with the link to jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Even i tried the same code, But i am not able to get it. Here is (Myjsfiddle)http://jsfiddle.net/SsNewbie/PKdhL/. I have found similar (jsfiddle)http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/SSgxM/ . But There the data-icon="arrow-r" is missing. When i insert it in list tag its not at all showing the list image. Do i ned to write some jquery code for this?

Comment: @SsNewbie where is the CSS / Graphic / Icon for the check mark?

Comment: All css , icon and icon properties are  inside jquerymobile.css. I need to override it?